# String split issue with user entered data

Tags: java, string

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 String read = scan.readLine();
 String str = read + ":" + "world";
 String[] sets = str.split(":");
 System.out.println(sets[0] + sets[1]);
}
```

Here, if we enter `hello`, I get `hello world`. But, when a user enters data which has ":", then the entered string is also split and ":" will not be printed. What can be done to not split entered data that contains ":"?

Comment: You split **on** the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not split on the same character the user could type himself.

Even if it's probably too much you could be sure that it won't happen again using an **uuid** as separator.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String read = scan.readLine();
String separator = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
String str = read + separator + "world";
String[] sets = str.split(separator);
System.out.println(sets[0] + sets[1]);
```

Comment: You should test if user data doesn't contain randomed separator and if it does random it again until it doesn't. I am not sure if uuid can have some regex metacharacters so if it can split should be done on `Pattern.quote(separator)`.

Comment: `UUID` string representation contains only `[0-9a-f-]`, 32 characters (36 including the `-`) that the user may *accidentally* type and match it seems near-impossible to me, but yes you could check for it, just to be **really** sure this time :-).

Comment: @Pshemo How do we do this with `Patten.quote(separator)` ?

Comment: @user1739812 `str.split(Pattern.quote(separator))`

Comment: @Alex I tried that first. It did not work! Thought there would be some other way to do it! Anyways I'll accept this as the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obvious and easy solution: If possible change your delimiter. You can also use a pipe (|), #, $, many more! Just find one about which you are sure that it won't appear in the input! You may even try with a combination of delimiters if you use regex!

Say if your delimiter is :; (colon followed by semi-colon) you can split like this using regex:

```
str.split("[:]{1}[;]{1}");
```

It means exactly one colon followed by exactly one semi-colon!

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

Try like this below:

```
    char[] delims = {':'};
        for (char delim : delims) {
        for (int i = 0; i < read.length(); i++) {
            if (read.charAt(i) == delim) {
                //Now write your code here
    String str = read + "world";
            }
else
{
String str = read + ":" + "world";
}
         }
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation :

```
public String[] split(String regex)

Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
str.split(/*regex*/);
```

removes the ***delimiter/regex provided to split() from the provided string*** and returns an String array. That's why you are not seeing `:` in the returned string array from `split()`

[**Link to DOCS**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I know how string split works. I was looking for a solution to the above problem!